# How can i send text entered in a search view to a function as a string after the search button is clicked?

Tags: android, android-search

Here is an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.thinkx.thinkx.friends"
android:background="#84cae6">
<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:queryHint="  Search ...."
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp">
</SearchView>
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And now i want to display the text in this recycler view by replacing the progressbar.
I have already seen the android documentation on searchview and also searcched a lot of questions but it didn't work for me!!

Comment: What do you want to do , call API ?

Comment: @Abhishekkumar I want to send the string as an http Post method to a php file to return the rows that matches with the string entered in the text and returns a json object to display it in this recycler view.

Comment: But i have written the rest of code i just want to know how to send that text to a function of the java class related to that xml file so pls help:)

Comment: I answered your question, Please check @Vishal, Any issue please comment

Comment: Please check answer below. you might get your things done with an ease

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add this to your code:**

```
search.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                // Do something when Search icon is clicked on Keyboard, will occur only when Search Icon is pressed
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                // do something on text change, it will occur on a single change
                    return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: This is what i wanted thanks for the help i wanted to filter the searches on text change!!

Comment: Then you will get your things done with this mate! Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Use below code :

**Without search button :** Here i'm using `TextWatcher` by this when your character changes on `SearchView`/`EditText`it will method:

```
editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if(editTextSearch.getText().length()>=1){

             callJsonRequest(editTextSearch.getText().toString());  // 

        }
    });
```

**With search button :**

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                hideKeyboard();
                if (utils.haveNetworkConnection()) {
                    if (validationDetails()) {
                        String searchText= editTextSearch.getText().toString();
                        callJsonRequest(searchText);
                      }   
            }
        });




public void callJsonRequest(String text){

}
```

Comment: Welcome Vishal , Happy to help you